# how to load test (more than 20 users) a web application using selenium grid

Tags: selenium-grid

I have tried using Selenium Grid to test a website for 20 users, but it is actually simulating only 12 users. I want to test the application for 500 users. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium might not be the right tool for load testing. You should probably check JMeter or some other performance testing tool. As mentioned in the selenium site, Selenium is primarily a functional testing tool. 
If you would still like to use Selenium Grid to do this testing, please provide more details on the error you are getting.